# How to substitute type by child type in function definition in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
interface Parent {
    name: string;
}

interface Child extends Parent {
    name: string;
    text: string;
}

function myFunction(text: string, target: Child): Child {
    target.text = text;
    console.log(target);
    return target;
}

const testChild: Child = {
    name: 'test',
    text: 'sample',
};

declare type FunctionType = (text: string, target: Parent) => Parent;

const func: FunctionType = myFunction;

func('newText', testChild);
```

This code leads to an error, because FunctionType awaits a function that has Parent (instead of Child) as one of arguments and result. Is there a way to make it works with direct descendants of Parent (like Child is)?

When it might be useful? 
Let's imagine we have Angular component that accepts simple slim items (like our Parent) and handler function, but we want to give a Child item and corresponding handler function (myFunction in our case) to this component. All component's internal functions touch only Parent-related fields.
I know that it is possible to create a subclass for parent component's class in Angular and override properties. But this will be a pain to create a new component or class for each new 'Child' type.
It's only for example.

My general question is how to define function type that will accept not only Parent interface, but also all child interfaces (without listing children)?

Actually I am trying to implement basic substitution principle: What works for parent should work for children.

Comment: "What works for parent should work for children".  If you have a `parent` variable of type `Parent`, you can call `func("", parent)`, right?  But `myFunction("", parent)` will do bad things.  So the substitution principle says you *can't* use `myFunction` as the value of `func`.  What is your use case (with code)?  You can change `FunctionType` to be something generic, but I don't know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can make generic to make it work, which seems to be the way to go in your case:

```
declare type FunctionType<T extends Parent = Parent> = (text: string, target: T) => T;

const func: FunctionType<Child> = myFunction;
```

[playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=23&ssc=46&pln=20&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApyhcyDeAoZQ5EOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG48BfPPUSWRFAYQAWwADYATZBAAekEKOpoMWMLgJES5KrXohmqwpGma6jFuzwwAriARhgAexDJSATwBiVm-ZAAKA2CPaDAA0yGAYDBD+yIIiogCUVDFiKkSh4ZEAdH7IALyhUmAsqQgO1HbCEBnCdgy+6WBxRUSYYBZQjmFQEYVsHCUgtPm0SaKJQsl5+KnqlMgA5JC0c0F6+Ybz1GQADhXLbCx4ohAIwoqhzlso7ta2DgAqFxAAPHcS0lhyCpjYeejfYAA+XLIXwFAKMEKdbpUO5xXJAu4HfqDSzWKjXTz3R5PEZAvIuDG3EAHVEIbxzEAQADudwKyyGYBGjSAA)

example to show it only works with descendants of `Parent`, because of `T extends Parent`:

[playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApyhcyDeAoZQ5EOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG48BfPPUSWRFAYQAWwADYATZBAAekEKOpoMWMLgJES5KrXohmqwpGma6jFuzwwAriARhgAexDJSATwBiVm-ZAAKA2CPaDAA0yGAYDBD+yIIiogCUVDFiKkSh4ZEAdH7IALyhUmAsqQgO1HbCEBnCdgy+6WBxRUSYYBZQjmFQEYVsHCUgtPm0SaKJQsl5+KnqlMgA5JC0c0F6+Ybz1GQADhXLbCyc4NDwSMgAIjUpRABGGADW1FTXduUQcCCmHKIQCMKKoc4tih3NZbA4ACqAiAAHnBEmkWDkCkw2Dy6BRYAAfLlkL4CgFGCFOt0qOC4rlseCDv1BpZrFQQZ4IVDoRcGNi8i5GWCPhw6QhvHMQBAAO7ggrLIZgEaNIA)

Comment: Not exactly what I need. Your example states that myFunction will definitely work with <Child>. But in my case it may be any other function with same signature but different child type. 
I am looking something like `FunctionType<any>`, but instead of `any` only Parent's descendants and Parent itself might be used.

Comment: @splash27 I've added an example of a non working version which uses a class that does not descends from Parents. As you can see, it will show an error